# Split 1 character after specified character

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

`var str = "4 items in My Favorites";`

I am trying to get "4 items in" and store it in a variable. I have been able to get "4 items i" but how do I include the one character after?

I have:

`var str = str.split("n")[0];`

which returns  "4 items i".

Comment: Or, `/\d+ items? in/.exec(str)[0]`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the index of the first "n", add 1 and take the substring:

```
str = str.substr(0, str.indexOf('n') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `substring` :

```
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('n') + 1);
```

Or a regular expression plus `match` or `replace` :

```
str = str.match(/^.+?in/).pop();
str = str.replace(/^(.+?in).*$/, '$1');
```

Comment: Why do you use a different end position depending whether the number is greater than 1? I guess you're assuming that it will just say `1 item in` rather than `1 items in`. But what about `0 items in`?

Comment: Well... Sorry for the copy-paste ^^'